# Кодировка символов кириллицы в отчетах allure

Tags: python, кодировка, pytest, allure

Использую allure-pytest для просмотра отчетов автотестов.
В автотестах прикладываю к отчетам JSON (строкой, НЕ файлом), который может содержать символы кириллицы, например:

```
{
  "measure": 0,
  "name": "Тест",
  "payment_method": "full_prepayment",
  "payment_object": 1,
  "price": 100.0,
  "quantity": 1.0,
  "sum": 100.0
}
```

Прикрепляю примерно так:

```
allure.attach(str({"measure": 0, "name": "Тест", "payment_method": "full_prepayment", "payment_object": 1, "price": 100.0, "quantity": 1.0, "sum": 100.0}), 'comment')
```

При просмотре отчета символы кириллицы отображаются неправильно:
[image: allure]

При этом, если прикреплять полностью текст из кириллицы - отображается нормально.

Не могу понять, как можно указать кодировку при прикреплении JSON к отчету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что не указана кодировка при чтении файла конфигурации.
До этого смог пофиксить так:

```
allure.attach(str(data).encode('cp1251'))
```